# Will faster encoding affect the quality in the end? (h.264)

Tags: video, editing

If I speed up the encoding in blender to real-time for quicker encoding, will the actual quality of the video go down? Or will the file just be bigger? Just trying to make videos for my YouTube

Comment: If Blender could make same-quality video using a faster preset, why would it use a slower preset?

Comment: Speed, quality, file size. Pick two.